# Prepend cells with certain text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to take some of my cells that look like this:

```
PETROLIA ONTARIO CANADA NON1RO,              
VANCOUVER BC V5L3B1,              
ONTARIO CANADA LOR2C0,              
DN58BY ENGLAND,              
DN58BY ENGLAND,
```

and change them into this:

```
(intl) PETROLIA ONTARIO CANADA NON1RO,              
(intl) VANCOUVER BC V5L3B1,              
(intl) ONTARIO CANADA LOR2C0,              
(intl) DN58BY ENGLAND,              
(intl) DN58BY ENGLAND,
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the CONCATENATE formula. the below example assumes your first value is in cell A1.

```
=CONCATENATE("(intl) ", A1)
```

Comment: How do I copy and paste the raw data instead of copying and pasting something that's dependent on a formula? If I copy and paste that stuff into the original column, I get recursion.

Comment: when you Copy and Paste, make sure you paste the values only. This can be accomplished by Right-Click > Paste Special > Values

Answer (score 2):

I think using the concatenate function requires unnecessary typing. Just use the ampersand sign to concatenate values:

```
="(intl) " & A1
```

I think that's easier.

Answer (score 1):

If the above data is in cells A1-A5, you can get the desired result if you put the following in cell B1:

```
=CONCATENATE("(intl) ", A1)
```

and copy-paste it to B2-B5

Comment: [Dupe](http://superuser.com/questions/209453/prepend-cells-with-certain-text-in-excel/209459#209459).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the following into the first column of the next and drag the bottom left corner of that cell down:

```
=CONCATENATE("(intl) ", INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0))
```