# Prepend text for spreadsheet

Tags: worksheet-function, formatting, spreadsheet, date-time, gnumeric

I want to have a string value prepended to a XL-style formating in a spreadsheet program ([gnumeric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnumeric)). The current formatting is `[$-f4f2]hh:mm` which should take `1:00 PM` as input and convert/display it as `13:00`. Additionally I would like to have it prepend the character `@`, such that with input `5:55pm` the cell converts it to `@17:55`.

I am asking on Super User since it was suggested as a good site for Excel-type questions in another user's Q/A on meta [<sup>1</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spradsheet-formulas-belong-on)<sup>,</sup>[<sup>2</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions).

I've already tried stuff such as `CONCATENATE("("a") ", [$-f4f2]hh:mm)` and `[$-f4f2]hh:mm & "@"` based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/209453/prepend-cells-with-certain-text-in-excel).

Comment: How does the formula that converts 12 hour time to 24 hour time work?

Comment: @Raystafarian I'm not actually sure, it is included as a custom format example in gnumeric. It does work though.

Comment: In Excel I'd use `TEXT()` for the reformatting of the time. I'm not acquainted with gnumeric.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting string doesn't allow theusual prepending of text, for a reason I do not know.

However, you don't need this format for your data. The portion in brackets affects only the display of month names, and since your data will be times, it is of no importance at all. In fact, it is a problem.

So, remove it. Add the text character to the beginning. All set:

```
\@hh:mm  or  "@"hh:mm
```

and Excel will add the "@"character.

That, I believe, is what is asked for. The answers seem to take the view that you want a string output. Just use one of the above formats as the format in a `TEXT` function if that is so.